# Lingering on Java 1.8.0_60 Applet breakpoints causes crash

Tags: java, debugging, applet

I have a simple Java applet that I'm running from an HTML page on my computer (i.e. file:///C....).  It works fine even when I start it in debug mode, which I do with "suspend=y".  When I attach the debugger it works great if breakpoints are disabled.  It also works fine if I stop at breakpoints and quickly go on to the next one, if any.  The problem arrises only when I linger on a breakpoint about 7 to 9 seconds.  If I do that the application crashes: The Java console disappears without any messages, the jp2launcher.exe task terminates, and the debugger "disconnects".

I would like to know whether or not other people have this problem debugging Applets with Java 1.8.0_60.  If you can take your time about moving on from a breakpoint I'd like to know what you're doing differently.  A breakpoint's not much good if you don't have time to look at the state of things.

I've searched Stack Overflow for tags [applet] and [debugging] with any of the words "crash", "stop", and "terminate" but found only one, irrelevant question.

My environment: I'm running 32 bit Java 1.8.0_60 on 64 bit Windows 7.  I run my Applet in Internet Explorer or Firefox.  I'm using the IntelliJ debugger. I'd try a different version of Java but that's not an option these days, I believe, without removing all recent versions of Java from my computer - a lot of trouble since I'd need to install them all again.

Comment: I've reported this bug to Oracle.

Comment: Still a problem in Java 1.8.0_66

Comment: I've reported the issue to Oracle. They requested an example and I sent it to them in December.